# React Native Webview Google Sign In(Android) error : Couldn't sign you in This browser or app may not be secure

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, google-signin

Using React Native WebView and there are two options for login 1. LinkedIn (which is working properly) 2. Google Sign In which is not working it shows error :
Couldn't Sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure .
[This is Error of Google Sign In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLVRc.jpg)Try using a different browser. If you 're already using a support browser, you can try again to sign in

Comment: anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please use User Agent correctly...

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

<WebView source={{ uri: redirectUrl }}
                    userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36" />
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/HEAD/docs/Getting-Started.md -setup for Android and IOS

Comment: This removed the first screen but showed an error when I inputted by login credentials on Google

Comment: this is not working at credtials screen again error.